# Получить данные из словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, словари

Исходные данные - это список из словарей, в каждом словаре по два элемента:

```
data = [
    {'symbol': 'USDRUB', 'lastPrice': '65.161315', 'startPrice': '66.254689'},
    {'symbol': 'EURRUB', 'lastPrice': '71.254632', 'startPrice': '71.342689'},
    {'symbol': 'GBPRUB', 'lastPrice': '99.854672', 'startPrice': '99.224289'},
    {'symbol': 'CADRUB', 'lastPrice': '23.215645', 'startPrice': '23.474643'},
]
```

Мне нужно посчитать по формуле цены для интересующих меня пар, представленных в списке ниже:

```
my_pairs = [['USDRUB','GBPRUB'],['EURRUB','CADRUB']]
```

Нужно, например, поделить `lastPrice` пары доллара на `lastPrice` пары фунта, затем добавить результат в список на нулевую позицию. На первую позицию результат деления цен двух пар из второго списка. На выходе должено быть примерно так:

```
summ = [0.66, 3,21]
```

Или не считать, а просто добавить в новый список необходимые мне цены в правильной последовательности, поделить то их просто:

```
new_list = [[65.161315,99.854672],[71.254632,23.215645]]
```

У меня выходит только с одним списком из двух валют, но если два списка как в примере, то получается путаница:

```
newlist= []

for onedict in (data):
    for pair in my_pairs:
        if onedict ['symbol'] == pair[0]:
            a1=(onedict ['lastPrice'])
            newlist.insert(0,a1)

        if onedict ['symbol'] == pair[1]:
            a2=(onedict ['lastPrice'])
            newlist.insert(1,a2)
print(newlist)
```

**UPD**

я добавил третий элемент в словарь и мне нужно при делении взять `lastPrice` для первого элемента в списке и поделить на `startPrice` второго элемента в списке.

Comment: Возможно стоит убрать нагромождение словарей и оставить кортежи вида (pair, lastPrice)? Код станет понятнее

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/389038)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант без использования фреймворков. Будет работать, если значения `symbol` - уникальны.

Можно обратить внимание на конструктор `data_dict`. Для `dict` существует синтаксический сахар, аналогичный `list`.

```
data = [
    {'symbol': 'USDRUB', 'lastPrice': '65.161315', 'startPrice': '66.254689'},
    {'symbol': 'EURRUB', 'lastPrice': '71.254632', 'startPrice': '71.342689'},
    {'symbol': 'GBPRUB', 'lastPrice': '99.854672', 'startPrice': '99.224289'},
    {'symbol': 'CADRUB', 'lastPrice': '23.215645', 'startPrice': '23.474643'},
]
my_pairs = [['USDRUB','GBPRUB'],['EURRUB','CADRUB']]

data_dict = {i['symbol']: i for i in data}

result = [float(data_dict[i[0]]['lastPrice']) / float(data_dict[i[1]]['startPrice']) for i in my_pairs]
# Эквивалентно:
# result = []
# for i in my_pairs:
#     x = float(data_dict[i[0]]['lastPrice'])
#     y = float(data_dict[i[1]]['startPrice'])
#     result.append(x/y)

print(result)
```

При таком варианте не нужно пробегать по списку `data`, в поисках каждого элемента `my_pairs`.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

data = [
  {'symbol': 'USDRUB', 'lastPrice': '65.161315'}, 
  {'symbol': 'EURRUB', 'lastPrice': '71.254632'},
  {'symbol': 'GBPRUB', 'lastPrice': '99.854672'}, 
  #  NOTE:    ^^^
  {'symbol': 'CADRUB', 'lastPrice': '23.215645'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("symbol").astype("float").T
```

получится такой DataFrame:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
symbol        USDRUB     EURRUB     GPBRUB     CADRUB
lastPrice  65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645
```

задаем формулы расчетов:

```
In [14]: formulas = '\n'.join([f"{pair[0][:3]}_{pair[1][:3]} = {pair[0]} / {pair[1]}" 
                               for pair in my_pairs])

In [15]: print(formulas)
USD_GBP = USDRUB / GBPRUB
EUR_CAD = EURRUB / CADRUB
```

считаем:

```
df = df.eval(formulas)
```

результат:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
symbol        USDRUB     EURRUB     GBPRUB     CADRUB   USD_GBP   EUR_CAD
lastPrice  65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645  0.652562  3.069251


In [35]: summ = df.iloc[0, -len(my_pairs):].to_list()

In [36]: print(summ)
[0.652561504583381, 3.0692505851118934]
```

Comment: Ради этого целый `pandas` тянуть? Слишком жирно, на мой взгляд. Но решение - познавательно.

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov, "лень - двигатель прогресса" ;)

Comment: Получается, что так не всплывает опечатка с GPBRUB из data, и GBPRUB из pairs?

Comment: @EurobeatIntensifies, именно из-за этой опечатки я добавил в ответ `data = [...]` ;)

Comment: @MaxU, а, я понял, меня смутило, что задания `my_pairs` нет в ответе, поэтому я не смог заметить исправление (подумалось, что как-то так вышло, что они просто рассмотрелись без исключения или ошибки как разные ключи)

Comment: Спасибо, pandas, похоже, самое то, потому что  списков там гораздо больше.

Comment: Я усложнил задачу, посмотрите пж-та. В формуле "{pair[0]} / {pair[1]}" вы не делали акцента, что это именно 'lastPrice', а теперь сделать надо, потому что я добавил еще 'startPrice'

Comment: исправил, готово

Comment: еще раз поправил data

Answer (score 2):

**Прошу обратить внимание, что лучше не использовать `SymPy` таким образом**. [Вот почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1010540/253345).

Раз уж мы не ищем тут легких путей:

`pandas` занимается таблицей, `sympy` занимается формулой. Все, как по науке...

```
import pandas as pd
from sympy import symbols

data = [{'symbol': 'USDRUB', 'lastPrice': '65.161315'},
        {'symbol': 'EURRUB', 'lastPrice': '71.254632'},
        {'symbol': 'GBPRUB', 'lastPrice': '99.854672'},
        {'symbol': 'CADRUB', 'lastPrice': '23.215645'}]

my_pairs = [['USDRUB','GBPRUB'],['EURRUB','CADRUB']]

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("symbol").astype("float").T
x, y = symbols('x y')
formula = x/y

summ = []
for i in my_pairs:
    xy = zip([x, y], df.loc['lastPrice'][i])
    summ.append(formula.subs(xy).n())

print(df, formula, summ, sep='\n------\n')
```

Результат:

```
symbol        USDRUB     EURRUB     GBPRUB     CADRUB
lastPrice  65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645
------
x/y
------
[0.652561504583381, 3.06925058511189]
```

Comment: интересное использование `sympy`)

Comment: Не нашел других "монстров", которых можно запихнуть в решение этой задачи, а потом оправдать. Подумал про `numpy`, но напал "двигатель прогресса". )

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на обновленный вопрос:

```
In [124]: df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("symbol").astype("float").T

In [125]: df
Out[125]:
symbol         USDRUB     EURRUB     GBPRUB     CADRUB
lastPrice   65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645
startPrice  66.254689  71.342689  99.224289  23.474643

In [126]: formulas = '\n'.join([f"{pair[0][:3]}_{pair[1][:3]} = {pair[0]} / {pair[1]}" for pair in my_pairs])

In [127]: print(formulas)
USD_GBP = USDRUB / GBPRUB
EUR_CAD = EURRUB / CADRUB

In [128]: df = df.loc[["lastPrice"]].eval(formulas)

In [129]: df
Out[129]:
symbol        USDRUB     EURRUB     GBPRUB     CADRUB   USD_GBP   EUR_CAD
lastPrice  65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645  0.652562  3.069251

In [130]: summ = df.iloc[0, -len(my_pairs):].to_list()

In [131]: summ
Out[131]: [0.652561504583381, 3.0692505851118934]
```

или так:

```
In [151]: df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("symbol").astype("float").T

In [152]: df
Out[152]:
symbol         USDRUB     EURRUB     GBPRUB     CADRUB
lastPrice   65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645
startPrice  66.254689  71.342689  99.224289  23.474643

In [153]: res = df.query("index == 'lastPrice'").eval(formulas)

In [154]: res
Out[154]:
symbol        USDRUB     EURRUB     GBPRUB     CADRUB   USD_GBP   EUR_CAD
lastPrice  65.161315  71.254632  99.854672  23.215645  0.652562  3.069251

In [155]: summ = res.iloc[0, -len(my_pairs):].to_list()

In [156]: summ
Out[156]: [0.652561504583381, 3.0692505851118934]
```

Comment: Результат тот же самый получился, что и при первом расчете. А должен быть другой.  "При делении взять lastPrice для первого элемента в списке и поделить на startPrice второго элемента в списке." Ответ [0.656707300769875, 3.0353872474226766]

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, циклы разумней вкладывать друг в друга в иной последовательности, поскольку, в общем-то, именно элементы `my_pairs` определяют уже то, что нужно искать в `data`:

```
# проходимся по всем парам, которые нужно анализировать
for pair in my_pairs:
    # находим словарь, в котором по ключу 'symbol' лежит элемент pair[0],
    # и берём соответствующее значение
    one = [float(el['lastPrice']) for el in data if el['symbol'] == pair[0]][0]
    # то же для pair[1]
    two = [float(el['lastPrice']) for el in data if el['symbol'] == pair[1]][0]

    # собственно, результат
    print(one, two)
```

---

Какие могут быть проблемы:

Если в `data` нет элемента с ключом `pair[0]` или `pair[1]`, то список, у которого берётся первый элемент (с индексом 0), будет пуст и выбросится `IndexError` (что у меня и случилось, потому что в `data` есть значение с опечаткой `GPBRUB`, а в `pairs` - `GBPRUB`, они не равны -> выбрасывается исключение).

Также, если уникальность не гарантирована (в `data` много элементов с значением по ключу `symbol` равным `pair[0]` или `pair[1]`), список будет более чем из 1 элемента. Это не ошибка, но подразумевает то, что подход (со взятием первого элемента) может давать результат, отличный от ожидаемого.