# Тест производительности "операторы Python" против SymPy и numexpr

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, sympy

Насколько расчеты встроенными операторами Python быстрее, чем расчет по формуле `SymPy` и `numexpr`?

Comment: `SymPy` умеет использовать в качестве `backend` другие модули, например `numpy` или даже `tensorflow`. Проблема в том, что в качестве примеров используются только простейшие формулы и чаще всего скаляры

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как на счет использования <s>анаболиков</s> [numexpr](https://pypi.org/project/numexpr/2.6.1/)?

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

lst = list(combinations(range(1, 23), 6))
X = np.array(lst) 

formula = """(a+b)*c-(d/e)**f"""

def std_op(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        result.append((i[0]+i[1])*i[2]-(i[3]/i[4])**i[5])
    return result

def anabolics(X, formula):
    d = {
        "a": X[:, 0],
        "b": X[:, 1],
        "c": X[:, 2],
        "d": X[:, 3],
        "e": X[:, 4],
        "f": X[:, 5],
    }
    return ne.evaluate(formula, d)
```

---

**тесты:**

```
In [17]: sum(std_op(lst))
Out[17]: 8083104.010504639

In [18]: anabolics(X, formula).sum()
Out[18]: 8083104.01050503
```

**скорость:**

```
In [19]: %timeit std_op(lst)
44.1 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [20]: %timeit anabolics(X, formula)
590 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**вывод:**  `numexpr` + `numpy` в ~75 раз быстрее `Vanilla Python`:

```
In [21]: 44.1*1000 / 590
Out[21]: 74.7457627118644
```

Comment: Это было действительно неожиданно! :)

Comment: @AntonAbrosimov Очень даже ожиданно. А если у вас получился противоположный результат, то скорее всего вы применяли модуль не для того, для чего он предназначен. Или тест был неправильный. Или еще что-нибудь.

Answer (score 4):

#### Код теста:

```
from itertools import combinations
from sympy import symbols

lst = list(combinations(range(1, 23), 6))

a, b, c, d, e, f = symbols('a b c d e f')
formula = (a+b)*c-(d/e)**f
print(formula)

def std_op(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        result.append((i[0]+i[1])*i[2]-(i[3]/i[4])**i[5])
    return result

def sympy(lst):
    result = []
    for i in lst:
        result.append(formula.subs(zip([a, b, c, d, e, f], i)).n())
    return result

%timeit std_op(lst)
result = std_op(lst)
print(len(result), result[0], result[-1])
%timeit sympy(lst)
result = sympy(lst)
print(len(result), result[0], result[-1])
```

#### Результат теста:

```
c*(a + b) - (d/e)**f
19.3 ms ± 205 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
74613 8.737856 664.6581501289133
18.4 s ± 81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
74613 8.73785600000000 664.658150128913
```

#### Итог:

Операторы Python победили с результатом: `19.3` **ms** против `18.4` **s** 18 секунд!

Таким образом, можно сделать вывод, что `SymPy` лучше не использовать в виде "калькулятора".